# What does the Signed keyword do in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, signed

I am working with a stored procedure. It is in MySQL. I am migrating it to SQL Server 2008. In MySQL stored procedure I found the following statement:

```
IF CONVERT(@intErrorNum,SIGNED) = -1
```

(where `@intErrorNum` is a variable).

What is the functionality of `Signed`? What does the above statement mean?

And also what will be the equivalent statement of `Signed` in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Word `SIGNED` is used to convert the string (or the passed value) in a signed integer (so it can be positive and negative).
You could also use `UNSIGNED` and your resulting number will be always non negative.

Comment: @user1018213: was this the answer you needed?